# Returning an array containing values from two passed in arrays

Tags: java, array

This is a simple piece of code which takes two arrays supplied as parameters, then appends them to  a new array that contains the values from the supplied arrays. Any suggestions for improvement would be greatly appreciated.

```
public static int[] append(int[] list1, int[] list2) {
    int[] appendedList = new int[list1.length + list2.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
        appendedList[i] = list1[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
        appendedList[i + list1.length] = list2[i];
    }
    return appendedList;
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's a whole lot to say... Looks about as simple as it can get, IMO

Comment: Haha, thanks! I think I'll try a different problem then, and close this as an answer myself if there's no other feedback.

Comment: @Phrancis there's *always* something to say ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could offload some of the work to `Arrays.copyOf` and `System.arraycopy`:

```
public static int[] append(int[] first, int[] second) {
  int[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length + second.length);
  System.arraycopy(second, 0, result, first.length, second.length);
  return result;
}
```

Comment: ah, I like `first` and `second`

Comment: @Mat'sMug It's surely less confusing that `list1` and `list2`. My very first thought was "`Arrays.copyOf` and lists don't fit together".

Comment: Love the fact that you're able to consolidate the code so much.

Comment: This implementation is reputedly faster because `System.arraycopy()` is implemented natively.

Answer (score 6):

The code obviously works, and it's simple enough to read. I guess IMO what is missing is context. Consider adding JavaDoc, perhaps?

Example:

```
/**
 * The purpose of this class is to append sales from multiple stores in one array.
 * @param list1 An array of sales from store # 1
 * @param list2 An array of sales from store # 2
 * @TODO Rename list1 and list2 to more relevant names
 */
public static int[] append(int[] list1, int[] list2) {
    int[] appendedList = new int[list1.length + list2.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
        appendedList[i] = list1[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < list2.length; i++) {
        appendedList[i + list1.length] = list2[i];
    }
    return appendedList;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`list` seems like a misleading name/suffix to use - you're using *arrays*, not *lists*.

`append` is also a bit misleading, since you're really *merging* the inputs into a new output - and the function could say *what* is being merged, too. I'm thinking `mergeArrays`.

Other than that, maybe I'd just use `result` instead of `appendedList`, but that's just me using `result` for return values - maybe `appendedList` is a better, more meaningful naming.

You're accessing `list1.length` and `list2.length` a number of times... might want to extract two little locals there, and readability-wise, I'd probably add a bit of extra vertical whitespace, too:

```
public static int[] mergeArrays(int[] array1, int[] array2) {

    int length1 = array1.length
    int length2 = array2.length
    int[] result = new int[length1 + length2];

    for(int i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
        result[i] = array1[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < length2; i++) {
        result[i + length1] = array2[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: A "merge" is something clever, like in merge sort. I'd call it simply "concat". +++ Btw., I always use "result".

Comment: @maaartinus eh, `concat` would be ideal. er, no, `IEnumerable<T>.Contat` would be! ;-)

Comment: You surely mean `java.util.arrays.Concat`, right? Just no C# manners. :D:D:D

Comment: @maaartinus yeah yeah.... except `IEnumerable<T>` covers anything from an array to a list, dictionary, hashset or anything enumerable that's not even yet written :p

Comment: OK, this corresponds with `Iterable<T>`, except that arrays are special in Java. Unfortunately, Java came first.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 you can offload all the work to streams:

```
public class IntArrayConcatenator {

    /**
     * Concatenates two int arrays
     */
    public static int[] concat(int[] first, int[] second) {
        return IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(first), Arrays.stream(second)).toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Concatenates any number of int arrays
     */
    public static int[] concat(int[]... arrays) {
        return Arrays.stream(arrays).reduce(new int[0], IntArrayConcatenator::concat);
    }

}
```